# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, synchronization, .net-6.0

i got this error in my project

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.Object name: 'Senario01DbContext'.'

this my  AddCitiesToUserModelFilter class :

```
 public class AddCitiesToUserModelFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        private readonly Senario01DbContext _dbContext; 

        public AddCitiesToUserModelFilter(Senario01DbContext dbContext) { 
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public   async void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (IsAddUserEndpoint(context)) // Replace "AddUser" with your actual operation ID
            {
                // Get the list of cities from the database
                var cities =  await _dbContext.Customers.ToListAsync();

                // Create an enum schema for the list of cities
                var cityEnumSchema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "integer",
                    Enum = cities.Select(city => new OpenApiInteger(city.CityId) as IOpenApiAny).ToList(),
                };

                // Add the enum schema as a parameter to the "Add User" method
                operation.RequestBody.Content["application/json"].Schema.Properties["selectedCityId"] = cityEnumSchema;
            }
        }
        private bool IsAddUserEndpoint(OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var httpMethod = context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod;
            var relativePath = context.ApiDescription.RelativePath;

            // Customize the HTTP method and relative path to match your "Add User" API endpoint
            return httpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                   relativePath.Contains("api/Home/AddUser"); // Update the path as needed
        }
    }
```

and this is my dbcontext:

```
    public class Senario01DbContext : DbContext
    {
        public Senario01DbContext(DbContextOptions<Senario01DbContext> options): base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.City)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Customers)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<City>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("CityId");
                entity.HasMany(d => d.Customers)
                    .WithOne(p => p.City)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Your API", Version = "v1" });

    // Add a custom operation filter to include the list of cities in the "Add User" method's input parameters
    using (var scope = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Senario01DbContext>();
        c.OperationFilter<AddCitiesToUserModelFilter>(dbContext);
    }
});
```

i used repository insted of dbContext but is not work

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the use of `async void`. Specifically, `async void` doesn't provide a way for the calling code to know when it completes, so the DI scope is torn down while the db context is still in use.

Unfortunately, it looks like Swashbuckle doesn't support async filters:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1538
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2430

I recommend commenting on the issues above. In the meantime, you can make it work by removing the `async` keyword and replacing `await x` with `x.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. This will block threads in your server, reducing its scalability, but Swashbuckle's limitations leave you no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume because you're directly injecting the DB context into your service it's being disposed of in some way before you want to use it.

Try using the dbcontext factory in efcore instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

In this case your code would look something like this:

```
public class AddCitiesToUserModelFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<Senario01DbContext> _dbContextFactory; 

    public AddCitiesToUserModelFilter(IDbContextFactory<Senario01DbContext> dbContextFactory) { 
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }
    public   async void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (IsAddUserEndpoint(context)) // Replace "AddUser" with your actual operation ID
        {
            using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            // Get the list of cities from the database
            var cities =  await context.Customers.ToListAsync();

            // Create an enum schema for the list of cities
            var cityEnumSchema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "integer",
                Enum = cities.Select(city => new OpenApiInteger(city.CityId) as IOpenApiAny).ToList(),
            };

            // Add the enum schema as a parameter to the "Add User" method
            operation.RequestBody.Content["application/json"].Schema.Properties["selectedCityId"] = cityEnumSchema;
        }
    }
    private bool IsAddUserEndpoint(OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var httpMethod = context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod;
        var relativePath = context.ApiDescription.RelativePath;

        // Customize the HTTP method and relative path to match your "Add User" API endpoint
        return httpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
               relativePath.Contains("api/Home/AddUser"); // Update the path as needed
    }
}
```